# Performance benchmark for static html / images : lighthttpd vs Amazon S3?

Tags: html, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I would like to know what solution provides better performance for a high traffic static website:

The lighthttpd web server on an EC2 instance, or hosting the pages directly at Amazon S3? Are there any benchmarks?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like S3 is a solid solution in terms of cost, scalability and simplicity.

Although the right solution depends of various factors. I found a great article on the topic.

http://cloudcomments.net/2012/01/24/simple-static-web-hosting-ec2-vs-s3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the test and monitor methods , try this.

TOOLS TO CREATE LOAD ON THE WEBSITE

- You can us either "ab" to run the tests against the site.

  ```
   ab is a tool for benchmarking your Apache Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) server. It is designed to give you an impression of how your current Apache installation performs. This especially shows you how many requests per second your Apache installation is capable of serving. See how to use ab command.
  ```

TOOLS TO MEASURING PERFORMANCE

```
  *   httperf is a tool to measure web server performance. It speaks the HTTP protocol both in its HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 flavors and offers a variety of workload generators.  Following command causes httperf to create a connection to host www.cyberciti.biz send and receive the reply, close the connection, and then print some performance statistics.

   httperf --hog --client=0/1 --server=SITE_NAME --port=80 --uri=/ --send-buffer=4096 --recv-buffer=16384 --num-conns=1 --num-calls=1

 * apachetop --> This is a console-based (non-gui) monitoring tool which reads the server-status pages from one or more Apache servers and combines the information onto one easy monitoring screen. It displays the current number of reads, writes, keepalives etc, plus the overall number of requests/hits processed, the amount of data transferred, the number of requests & data processed per second since the Apache servers were started, and the 'current' per second numbers
```